# Writing SQL query to find ranking

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to determine for a given person how many people have a better score than they do, and group it by the different teams they belong to.  So, in the tables below, I'm grabbing the list of `team_id` from the `team_person` table where the person_id matches the person I care about.  That will get me all of the teams I belong to.

Then I need to know each `person_id` that is in any team I belong to so that I can find out what their maximum `score` is from the `performances` table.

Once I have that, I finally want to determine, for each `team_id`, how many people on that team have a better score than I do, where better is simply defined as having a larger value.

I've gotten way beyond my abilities with SQL at this point.  What I have so far, which seems to get me the maximum score for all the people I care about, (basically everything but my final "by team" requirement) is this:

```sql
    SELECT person_id, MAX(score) m
    FROM performances
    WHERE category_id = 7 AND person_id IN (
        -- Find all the people on the teams I belong to
        SELECT DISTINCT person_id
        FROM team_person 
        WHERE team_id IN (
            -- Find all the teams that I belong to
            SELECT DISTINCT team_id 
            FROM team_person
            WHERE person_id = 2
        )
    )
    GROUP BY person_id
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

My two relevant tables are defined like so, and I'm using psql 9.1.15

```
                                     Table "public.team_person"
   Column   |           Type           |                          Modifiers                      
------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 ident      | integer                  | not null default nextval('team_person_ident_seq'::regclass)
 team_id    | integer                  | not null
 person_id  | integer                  | not null
 *chop extraneous columns*
Indexes:
    "team_person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ident)
    "teamPersonUnique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (team_id, person_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "team_person_person_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(ident) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "team_person_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team(ident) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "roster" CONSTRAINT "roster_team_person_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_person_id) REFERENCES team_person(ident) ON DELETE SET NULL
Triggers:
    update_team_person_modified BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON team_person FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified_column()



                                      Table "public.performances"
   Column    |           Type           |                          Modifiers                       
-------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 ident       | bigint                   | not null default nextval('performances_ident_seq'::regclass)
 category_id | integer                  | not null
 person_id   | integer                  | not null
 score       | real                     | not null
 *chop extraneous columns*
Indexes:
    "performances_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ident)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "performances_category_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES performance_categories(ident) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "performances_person_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(ident) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Please provide sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and show the results you'd expect to get from that sample data. Otherwise any practical testing is going to involve everyone dumming up their own anyway...

Comment: Those extraneous columns aren't extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

First, state just the problem, without assumptions about how to get to the solution. You've done that fairly well:

> determine for a given person how many people have a better score than they do, and group it by the different teams they belong to.

but I'd rephrase a bit:

> For each team a given person is a member of, how many people in that team have a better score than the subject person?

I don't know about you, but it suddenly seems simpler now. Take the team table, left outer join team_person and filter for teams we're a member of, left outer join performances to find games we played with that team, left outer join team_person again to get other people who're members of each team, left outer join performances, filter out teams the subject person isn't a member of, group and aggregate.

It's underspecified for some corner cases (like a team where you're the only member, or a team where you didn't play a game), but *eh*, whatever.

---

Problems:

There's no team table. Since you don't care about anything in the team table, you can omit it from the join and just use `team_person` as the join root.

Your `team_person` table is defective, by the way. It should have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(team_id, person_id`). Or, better, that should be the `primary key`. It doesn't actually matter for this query because duplicate team memberships won't change the result, but it's bad data modelling. You can't be a member of a team more than once.

`performances` should also have a column identifying the particular game or whatever. Since you haven't shown one, I'm going to assume you mean that you're looking for people who, in any game, performed better than the subject person at least once, in that game or another game. If you actually want to find people who did better *in a particular game* then you need a suitable key on `performances`.

**Fatal problem**: `performances` is also missing a column linking the performance to the team. This makes it impossible to properly solve the problem because you can't get performances by a given person on a given team. I'm going to assume there is in fact a `team_id` on `performances` and you just left it out.

---

So, allowing for the above issues, I'd first acquire the data with a big join, then group and aggregate it. This join will give us, for each team we played in, for each of our performances, for each other player, for each of their other performances, one row with all the relevant information. You can then compare performances and aggregate.

The below is totally untested, since you didn't provide sample data and you chopped important parts out of your schema (or the schema is defective), but I'd try something like:

```
SELECT
  my_performances.team_id,

  -- Find how many distinct people scored better than us at least once,
  -- no matter how many times or in which game.
  COUNT(distinct other_team_person.person_id)

-- Start the join with our team memberships and how we scored in each.
-- If we didn't play any games for this team don't produce a result row
-- for it, so INNER JOIN.
FROM team_person my_team_person
INNER JOIN performances my_performances ON 
  (my_performances.person_id = my_team_person.person_id 
   AND my_performances.team_id = my_team_person.team_id)

-- Other members of teams we're also a member of, skipping
-- ourselves. An `INNER JOIN` is fine here because we know
-- a team with only ourselves as a member isn't interesting
-- and we might as well skip it.
INNER JOIN team_person others_team_person ON (
  my_team_person.team_id = other_team_person.team_id
  AND my_team_person.person_id <> other_team_person.person_id)

-- How each of those people performed in each team they're in
-- (because of previous filter, only considers teams we're in too).
-- INNER JOIN because if they never played they can't beat us.
INNER JOIN performances other_performances ON (
  other_team_person.person_id = other_performances.person_id
  AND other_team_person.team_id = other_performances.team_id)

-- Make sure `my_team_person` is only teams we're a member of
WHERE my_team_person.person_id = $1

-- Also discard rows where the other person didn't do better than us
  AND my_performances.score < other_performances.score

-- Emit one row per team we're a member of
GROUP BY my_performances.team_id;
```

If you want to show teams where you never played and teams where you're the only player, you'll need to change some `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

If you want to compare to find people who beat you only within a given game, you're going to need an extra column on `performances`, then an extra term in the join on `other_performances` to restrict it to only matching in the same game as `my_performances`.

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  I'll work on getting a sqlfiddle setup.  My 'ident' fields are the primary key. Not sure why it didn't display that.  Is it better to make the pair the primary key like you suggested?  I can look into changing that.    A performance doesn't relate to a team.  It's just that I benched 350, for example.  So I'm wanting to find the most I bench pressed, and then compare that against the most other people bench press.  The team just comes into play for showing how I compare against other on that specific team.

Comment: @Gargoyle Generally join-tables like `team_person` have a composite primary key composed of the foreign key elements, like `PRIMARY KEY (team_id, person_id)` unless you're using a braindead framework like Ruby on Rails's ActiveRecord, which can't understand composite primary keys. It's acceptable in that case to have a synthetic primary key and then just a `UNIQUE (team_id, person_id)` constraint; it's less efficient but has the same effect.

Comment: Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17376 for a more concrete example.  I left out all the primary keys and relations and such and only included items specific to the query.

Comment: @Gargoyle you can omit the primary keys and have your schema still make sense?

Comment: yes because for now the primary key on every table is just "ident serial primary key". It's going to take some time to figure out how to do it properly, based on your feedback, but first I have to get the client's new feature implemented.  "team_id" for example is the reference to the team table's ident column.  person_id is the reference to the person table's ident columen, etc...   But for this ranking query, I don't have to worry about any of that.  Just getting back the team_id and rank is enough.